# How to display multiple or single images for a product page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here][1]
I'm trying to store multiple images in the database. I have products table and images tables. I have faced the issue for image not showing the product list page. I am trying to more tutorials codes unfortunately my issues not solve. Please check the below cods and help me the problem solve.

Products Model

```
  class Products extends Model
      {
          use HasFactory;
          protected $table = 'cw_products';
          protected $fillable = 
          ['product_id','product_title','product_details','product_cid']; 

          public function images() 
             {          
              return $this->hasMany(ProductsImage::class, 'images_pdct_id', 'images_id');        
             }
     }
```

ProductsImage Model

```
   class ProductsImage extends Model
     {
         use HasFactory;
         protected $table = 'cw_products_images';
         protected $fillable = 
         ['images_id','images_pdct_id','images_image','images_thumbnail'];

         public function products() 
            {
             return $this->belongsTo(Products::class, 'product_id');
            }

      }
```

ProductsController

```
       use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
       use Illuminate\Http\Request;
       use Illuminate\Support\Str;
       use App\Models\Products;
       use App\Models\ProductsImage;
       use Hash;
       use Session;
       use File;
       use Image;
       class ProductsController extends Controller
       {
         public function index(Request $request)
              {   
                 $data = array();        
                 //$products = Products::where('product_status', '>=', 0)->orderBy('product_id', 'desc')->paginate(30); // Replace 100 
                 $products = Products::with('images')->where('product_status', '>=', 0)->orderBy('product_id', 'desc')->paginate(30);
                 //DD($products);
                 return view('webadmin.pages.products',compact('data','products')); 
               }
        }
```

Products List View Page

```
        @if($products->count())
        @foreach($products as $product) 
         <tr style="color:rgb(26, 25, 25);">
            <td>
               @foreach($product->images as $pimages)    
               <!--$pdctImage = $product->images[0]->images_thumbnail;
               dd($pdctImage);   -->                                     
               <img src="../../assets/img/products/thumbnail/{{ $pimages->images_thumbnail }}" alt="ProjectImage" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 50%; height: 50px;"/>
               @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>{{ $product->product_title }}</td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach    
          @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation ships are defined using foreign key and local key like this - return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key'); -https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships . So you would need to change relationship in both models.

```
class Products extends Model
  {
      use HasFactory;
      protected $table = 'cw_products';
      protected $fillable = 
      ['product_id','product_title','product_details','product_cid']; 

      public function images() 
         {          
          return $this->hasMany(ProductsImage::class, 'images_pdct_id', 'product_id');        
         }
 }

class ProductsImage extends Model
 {
     use HasFactory;
     protected $table = 'cw_products_images';
     protected $fillable = 
     ['images_id','images_pdct_id','images_image','images_thumbnail'];

     public function products() 
        {
         return $this->belongsTo(Products::class, 'product_id','images_pdct_id');
        }

  }
```

Comment: Hi T.Shah, Thanks for your support. Products page image display issues solved. I have using the @foreach function in view page. how to display the single image showing the each product list. Please help.

Comment: You can access the first image like $product->images[0].

Comment: Hi T.Shah, Thanks for your support. Working now. I have used the below code.                   <td>                                                                    
        <img src="../../assets/img/products/thumbnail/{{ $product->images->first()->images_thumbnail }}" alt="ProductImage" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:25%"/>
    </td>